# Wait for a submit event to finish before calling async function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to run an async function after a form has completed its submit. The form updates a shopping cart, and I need to grab the products from the cart after they've been added.

I've tried a million things and nothing seems to wait until the form has COMPLETED submitting before running my code. I don't want to use any sort of timing events.

Here is the latest couple versions of code I have. They both do the same thing and run prior to the submit being finished:

```
window.addEventListener(
  'submit', 
  () => vueFreshie.$options.components['fresh-credit'].options.methods.getCart(), 
  false
)

window.addEventListener("submit", async e => {
  await vueFreshie.$options.components['fresh-credit'].options.methods.getCart()
}, false)
```

this is the Vue method I'm calling, and I've simplified it for examples sake.

```
  methods: {
    async getCart() {
      let response = await axios.get(`/cart.js`)
      debugger
    }
  }
```

the method is called fine, its just too early and the cart has not been updated.

Comment: One way I think you can achieve this is using `axios` to get the data from the form and posting it manually rather than making the `html` form submit data to the server. This way all you need to do is trigger that `axios` call on click of submit event and `await` for it to finish before calling the `getCart` function. Let me know if you need me to show you a demo.

Comment: @Salvino yes if you can show a demo that would be fantastic

Comment: The code really went wrong. Why would you need `submit` on `window`? Use Vue's event handling that exists in the scope of a component. Accessing methods through $options is deeply wrong, unless you should patch or extend a component in a way it wasn't designed, and there's no other way to fix it

Answer (score 1):

**Here you go:**
I've used a onSubmit event handler to listen to the form submission & [`axios`](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example) to explicitly post the data to my server. This way I have more control over the submission request and I can `await` for its completion before proceeding to the `getCart` API.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
      formData: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async onSubmit() {
      const {data} = await axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', this.formData);
      console.log('response from submitted request', data);
      await this.getCart();
    },

    async getCart() {
      console.log('safe to call the get cart API now');
      const {data} = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
      console.log('response from cart api', data);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <input name="firstName" v-model="formData.firstName"><br/>
    <input name="lastName" v-model="formData.lastName">
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

###### Reference

- [Event handling in Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

Comment: Shoot.. I'm sorry I should have been more clear.. I don't have access to the form being submitted. My code is installed on a website, and needs to function without any control over the form itself

Comment: @ToddT This is XY problem. Consider explaining the whole case in the question, so an appropriate solution could be suggested, instead of addressing a wrong approach on it. What you tried in the OP is hacky and should never be done, unless you hack into someone's else app, e.g. through browser extension.